# shortest path not changed if one of formula is used to update all weights

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

Weighted Directed Graph $G$ is given. there is no negative cycle. vertexes number is $1$ to $n$. weight of edge $a$ to $b$ is $P(a,b)$. $G'$ is graph $G$ with edges will be changed according to following formula. the shortest path (not about weights of shortest path, just shortest path) does not changed !!

**A)** $P'(a,b)=P(a,b)+a-b$

**B)** $P'(a,b)=P(a,b)+b-a$

here $a$ and $b$ in sum means number (i.e: $a,b$  are the numbers assigned to those two vertices.)

how we can get the point about this strange claims ?

Comment: Your equations A and B don't make much sense. You just cancel the $P'(a,b)$ from both sides, and get $a=b$. Do you mean $P'(a,b)=P(a,b)+a-b$ and $P'(a,b)=P(a,b)+b-a$? But I'm not sure that makes sense, either, since $P(a,b)$ is a number but $a$ and $b$ are vertices. So I suppose you mean $a,b$ are the *numbers* assigned to those two vertices. Please edit your question, carefully.

Comment: So, $n$ is $15$?

Comment: Hint1: The path weight telescopes

Comment: Pick a path s-t. Assume there is only one intermediate node u. Then the total weight (according to rule A) is $[P(s,u) + s - u] + [P(u,t) + u - t] =\\ P(s,u) + P(u,t) + s - t$. In other words, the new path weight is the old plus $s-t$. Now, do the same for more intermediate nodes.

Comment: They weight of every s-t path in G is increased by s-t in G'. So does the order change?

Comment: Davied please pay attention for a moment. You only care about the path, not its weight. Assume $G$ has $k$ s-t paths ordered $p_1 \le p_2 \le \dots \le p_k$. In $G'$ every path is increased by $s-t$. So the order doesn't change!

Comment: If you are sure you got it I recommend answering your question. It will be a good practice to write it formally and you can always tag me to check it.

Comment: I added an answer for both rules. By telescoping we refer to a technique where all terms but the first and last are cancelled with their next\previous. You may start reading more from the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any path $C$ between two nodes $s$ and $t$ in $G$ and let $w$ be its total weight. After applying the rule:$$P'(a,b) = P(a,b)\ \pm(a-b)$$ the new weight is:
\begin{align*}
w'(s,t) &= \sum_{(u,v)\ \in\ C} P'(u,v)\\
   &= \sum_{(u,v)\ \in\ C} [P(u,v) \pm (u - v)]\\
   &= \sum_{(u,v)\ \in\ C} P(u,v)\ \pm \sum_{(u,v)\ \in\ C}(u - v)\\
   &= w(s,t) \pm [(s - u_1) + (u_1 - u_2) + \cdots + (u_{n-1} - u_n) + (u_n - t)]\\
w'(s,t) &= w(s,t) \pm (s - t) 
\end{align*}
This tells us that all s-t paths in $G$ are changed by an equal amount of $s-t$ and therefore their ordering is preserved.

EDIT: As per request, I will add an example.
Assume the are 3 s-t paths in $G$ ordered like:
\begin{align*}
  &w_1(s,t) &\le &\ w_2(s,t) &\le &\ w_3(s,t) &\implies\\
  &w_1(s,t) \pm(s-t) &\le &\ w_2(s,t) \pm(s-t) &\le &\ w_3(s,t) \pm(s-t) &\implies \\
 &w'_1(s,t) &\le &\ w'_2(s,t) &\le &\ w'_3(s,t)
\end{align*}
And we see that the order remains the same.